# Are there other languages besides Perl with default variables?

Tags: perl

I have recently learnt about [Perl's default variable `$_`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlvar.pod#pod-_). A good article on topic is here http://perlmaven.com/the-default-variable-of-perl. I find the ability to apply functions to it without specifying the argument fascinating. Are there any other programming languages with similar facilities?

EDIT:
Some of the languages listed in comments are:

Powershell - should be very similar to Perl.

Groovy - has generic `it` iterator variable.

Scala - has `_` variable as generic lambda argument.

Lisp - has anaphoric macros.

HyperTalk and AppleScript - see @AmbroseChapel [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31645105/1646982)

Comment: You should look on esolang.org, particularly in joke languages.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, I will look there, but I was hoping to find something practical.

Comment: Ruby borrows `$_` from Perl, but its use isn't recommended these days, I think.

Comment: But in Ruby it means the last line read from STDIN as per http://ruby.wikia.com/wiki/Special_variable

Comment: Not really the same thing, but in some languages, the method call invocant defaults to the invocant of the currently executing method ("this", "self").

Comment: In Lisp you have anaphoric macros.

Comment: This is going to come across as sarcastic, but it's not: English. Larry Wall is a linguist. So when you say "Do you have the a phone? Can I borrow it?" or "Do you know Dave? Have you seen him?" you're using default variables, called pronouns. Larry deliberately chose natural-language-like structures for Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest rather than looking for a "default" variable, instead you consider it in terms of implicit variables. Those are rather more common.

If you look for example, at `awk` `sed` `grep` etc. - they apply their magic to 'the current line'.

E.g.

```
sed -e 's/fish/paste/g' myfile
```

Will implicitly *iterate* myfile, and apply the pattern once per line.

I think this is whence it came in perl - because perl lets you emulate sed:

```
perl -p -e 's/fish/paste/g' myfile
```

If you deparse this, you turn it into:

```
LINE: while ( defined ( $_ = <ARGV> ) ) {
    s/fish/paste/g;
} 
continue { 
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $!;
}
```

Perl's just being a bit more ... explicit about it's implicitness. I mean, once you start 'setting' an implicit variable in a `while` loop, then from there it makes sense to do so in a `for` loop.

I would urge caution though - I like `$_` but I don't like *writing* it - I feel that if I actually am, then I'd *usually* be better off with naming a variable instead.

As always with programming - and especially with `perl` - readability and clarity is king.

I think being able to write;

```
 my $regex = qr/some_pattern/;

 while ( <STDIN> ) {
    print if m/$regex/;
 }
```

Is clearer than:

```
while ( my $line = <STDIN> ) { 
    if ( $line =~ m/some_pattern/ ) { 
        print $line;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see where implicit variables originate from. Do you know of any newer languages, that borrow the idea from either Perl, or awk/sed/grep?

Comment: I've not run into any. But I think in no small part because newer languages are trying to be 'not perl' :). But you do have it to an extent with the use of e.g. `$i` or `i` as "generic iterator". It's not built into the language, but it is a fairly common programming habit. Some might call it a bad habit too.

Comment: And which languages have such generic iterators?

Comment: I know only of Groovy which has `it` generic iteration variable.

Comment: Powershell makes good use of the $_ variable for its implicit iterations (pipelines and whatnot).

Answer (score 1):

Scala has something like $_, for example

List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + 2)

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know of is HyperTalk, the language for Apple's slightly unusual development environment HyperCard, which has `it` as a default or implicit variable. You can do something like

```
get the length of <something>
put it into myVariable
```

and this kind of programming can also be done in AppleScript, see [the "it" and "me" keywords](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW4).